# Illustrator cannot add stroke to path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

Can someone tell me why i cannot add a stroke to the selected path?
I have opened the file multiple times/copied and pasted the paths and tried to change the color and weight of the stroke.

I believe this has to do with the circle being filled in. in the layer selection.

[image: screenshot]

illustrator says its adding a stroke but nothing shows up.

Comment: try to change the stroke color

Comment: i tried different colors and weights. its something with the circle being filled in but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you try this in a new file; try in a different layers and edit your question with more information of what you have tried? Better chance of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Appearance Panel.

The "meatball" or "circle being filled in" would indicate that there is some appearance setting on that path. It could be as simple as being set to 0% opacity or a blend mode which doesn't show the colors you are trying.

Select the path and choose `Clear Appearance` from the **Appearance Panel Menu**, then try adding your color stroke.

Comment: thank you for helping out, New to illustrator always worked in HTML coding design and now my employer wants some new talents.

Answer (score 0):

May be its behind another object. Select the path and then right click there
Then **Arrange >> Bring to front** or keyboard shortcut **Shift + Ctrl + ]**